# how to make the images appear one by one? flash as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, tween, gsap

i'm trying to make my images appear one by one, but they come on screen all together :

```
for (var i=0; i<myImages.length; i++){
    myImages[i].alpha = 0;
    myImages[i].buttonMode = true;
    TweenLite.to(myImages[i], 1, {delay:.5, alpha:1});
}
```

the delay is not the right option, do you have any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this small variation:

```
for (var i=0; i<myImages.length; i++){
    myImages[i].alpha = 0;
    myImages[i].buttonMode = true;
    TweenLite.to(myImages[i], 1, {delay:(0.5*i), alpha:1});
}
```

When you set up many TweenLite tweens on different images, if the **delay** and the **duration** of all tweenings is the same, all images will show up on screen at the same time, don't you think? ;)

So the solution is to increment the delay of the tween as you loop through the images.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i=0; i<myImages.length; i++){
    myImages[i].alpha = 0;
    myImages[i].buttonMode = true;
    TweenLite.to(myImages[i], 1, {delay:(i+1)*0.5, alpha:1});
}
```